# Each time new NSMutableDictionary added in plist even if I allocate it only once

Tags: iphone, plist, nsmutabledictionary

In my apps I have to save tag value of key `@"v_number"` from xml which chages each time from server in plist. Since I successfully able to update new updated value of key `@"v_number"` in plist.

But problem is as I run apps ,each time new NSMutableDictionary added.

But I want to add it only once in plist.

Does anybody have an idea, why each time dictate allocated?

```
NSArray *temp = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDirectory=[temp objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileAdd = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PList.plist"];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:fileAdd]) 
{
    PListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileAdd]; 
    main =  [PListArray objectAtIndex:0];
    t1 = [main objectForKey:@"v_number"];

}else
{
    PListArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    t1=@"0";
}
//main = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:fileAdd];


main = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];


[main setObject:t1 forKey:@"v_number"];
```

Comment: please post the code where you are updating the file

Comment: i updte the file in 
-(void) ParseXML: (NSString *)path method . in app del.

Comment: i wanted to see how u are updating the file to see why is it adding dictionaries rather than overwriting

Comment: i update by this way  [PListArray addobject:main]

Comment: sont you see the problem? u are using addObject then wondering why the object is being added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (main != nil) {
    main = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
}
```